# Why go programs print output to terminal screen but not /dev/stderr?

Tags: go, logging

As I see in the source of golang
go will print output to `os.Stderr` which is

```
Stderr = NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/dev/stderr")
```

So why I run this program in my terminal with the command `go run main.go`
the output is printed to the terminal screen, not the `/dev/stderr`

```
// main.go
func main() {
    log.Println("this is my first log")
}
```

Comment: @lurker, the standard `log` package is configured this way: it writes to stderr by default.

Comment: @kostix ah ok, duh, wasn't thinking about the "log" part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In standard Unix/Linux terminals, both `stdout` and `stderr` are connected to the terminal so the output goes there.

Here's a shell snippet to clarify this:

```
$ echo "joe" >> /dev/stderr
joe
```

Even though we echoed "joe" to something that looks like a file, it gets emitted to the screen. Replace `/dev/stderr` with `/tmp/foo` and you won't see the output on the screen (though it will be appended to the file `/tmp/foo`)

---

In Go you can specifically select which stream to output to by passing it to functions like `fmt.Fprintf` in its first argument.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, several things are going on here.

First, is that on a UNIX-like system (and you appear to be on a Linux-based one), the environment in which each user-space program runs, includes the concept of the so-called ["standard I/O streams"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) — that is, each program bootstrapped by the OS and taken control automatically has three file descriptors opened and available: representing the standard input stream, the standard output stream and the standard error stream.

Second, typically (but not always) the spawned program inherits these streams from its parent program. For the case of an interactive shell running in a terminal (or a terminal emulator), that parent program is the shell, and so the standard I/O streams of the spawned program are inherited from the shell.
The shell's standard I/O streams, in turn, naturally connected to the terminal it runs at: that's why it's possible to input data to the shell and read what it prints back: you actually type into the terminal, not to the shell; it's the terminal which delivers that data to the shell; the case for the shell's output is just the reverse.

Third, that `/dev/stderr` is a Linux-specific "hack" which is a virtual device meaning "whatever *my* stderr is connected to".
That is, when a process opens that special file, it gets back a file descriptor connected to whatever the process' stderr *is already connected to.*

Fourth, let's grok the code example you cited:

> `NewFile(uintptr(syscall.Stderr), "/dev/stderr")`

Here, a call to `os.NewFile` is made, receiving two arguments.
To cite it's documentation:

`$ go doc os.NewFile`

> `func NewFile(fd uintptr, name string) *File`
>   `NewFile` returns a new `File` with the given file descriptor and name. The returned value will be `nil` if `fd` is not a valid file descriptor.
>   <…>

OK, so this function takes a raw kernel-level
[file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)
and a name of the file *it is supposed to have been opened to.*
That latter bit is crucial: the OS kernel itself is (almost) oblivious about what sort of stream a file descriptor actually represents — at least as long as its public API is considered.

So, when `NewFile` is called to obtain an instance of `*os.File` for the program's standard error stream by the `log` package,
it *does not open* the file "/dev/stderr" (even though it exists);
it merely uses it's name since `os.NewFile` requests it.
It could have used "" there to much the same extent except for changes in error reporting: if something fails when using the resulting `*os.File`, the error output would not have included the name "/dev/stderr".

The `syscall.Stderr` value is merely the number of the file descriptor connected to the standard error stream.
On UNIX-compatible kernels it's always `2`; you can run `go doc syscall.Stderr` and see for yourself.

**To recap,**

- The call `NewFile(...)` you referred to does not open any files;
  it merely wraps an already open file descriptor connected to the standard error stream of the current process into a value of type `os.File` which is used throughout the `os` package for I/O on files.
- On Linux, the special virtual device file `/dev/stderr` does really exist but it has nothing to do with what's happening here.
- When you run a program in an interactive shell without using any  [I/O redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), the standard streams of the created process are connected to the same "sinks and sources" as those of the shell. And they, in turn, are most of the time connected to the terminal which hosts the shell.

Now I urge you to fetch an introductory book on the design of UNIX-like operating systems and read it.